# SubAntialiasing fonts

Tags: wpf, fonts, antialiasing

In some places, I got sub antialiasing on, and on another places, I dont.
I use "Display" rendering mode combined with ClearType.

However, it's really random, it uses grayscale antialiasing, instead of colourful one. And it looks bad. How can I force it?

It works differently, based on operating system I guess. But the weird part is, some places I have SubAA on, and another I dont.

And when on different windows, some places I have subAA on as a whole. Do you have any ideas why this inconsistency exists? I want SUBAA!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain situations when ClearType will get disabled in the rendering path which means it will then revert to grey scale anti-aliasing:

- When you use `AllowsTransparency="True"` on a `Window`
- When ClearType is disabled in Windows Settings (and you haven't used TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" to force the use of ClearType)
- ClearType text does not display correctly on a background that is not fully opaque i.e you introduce some transparency.
- If Text is rendered to an intermediate target due to the use of a:

  - VisualBrush
  - DrawingBrush
  - OpacityMask
  - Viewport2DVisual3D
  - Effect
  - BitmapEffect

Are you using `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` on your top level element i.e. Window? (the property is inherited so you if you put it there it should apply to everything in your Window).

You can use `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"` to re-enable ClearType in the rendering path but you may have artifacts because there was usually a good reason to disable it.

You can use `TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed"` when you have animations and you don't want to have lower-quality text rendering (i.e. ClearType disabled) while the animation is in effect.

You can use `TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"` to force ClearType to be used even then the Windows System Settings have not enabled it (this won't do anything special for you in this case, it's here for reference).

- http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx
- http://arbel.net/2007/02/03/give-me-back-my-cleartype/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong@setting TextBlock background.
You need to set parent element's background instead. It now works. 
But I found nasty bug. When you have TextBlock and use Wrapping there, then somehow some TextBlock elements calculate their width wrong, and they cut REALLY early, like 10x times early. I have no idea why(TextTrimming=characterEllipse).

Comment: Not sure if this is old or what but __TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"__ works pretty well